# Laravel Friendly url instead of ID

Tags: laravel, friendly-url

OK all I am so lost. The following prints our [] an empty array. This is really messing me up. AppServiceProvider to populate the dropdown

```
\View::composer(['layouts/frontend/partials/header'], function ($view) { $title = Weekend::all('title','id'); $view->with(['title'=>$title]); });
```

route
Route::get('weekends/{weekend:title}',[PagesController::class,'getCurrent']);`

Link to the individual page

````
 @foreach($title as $title) <li><a href="weekends/{{$title->title}}">{{$title->title}}</a></li> @endforeach``` controller ``` public function getCurrent(Weekend $title) { return $title; }
````

And the Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Webmaster;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Weekend extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [];


    public function weekendTeamMembers() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Webmaster\WeekendTeamMember::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'title';
    }


}

enter code here
```

I have everything working but I would like to have the url passing the weekend title instead of ID. Not sure how to do this. In my AppService Provider I have the following to populate the navbar dropdown with titles:

```
\View::composer(['layouts/frontend/partials/header'], function ($view) {
    $title = Weekend::all('title', 'id');

    $view->with(['title'=>$title]);
});
```

My route for each individual page is

```
Route::get('weekends/{weekend}', [PagesController::class, 'getCurrent']);
```

The Link is

```
@foreach ($title as $title)
    <li><a href="{{ $title->id }}">{{ $title->title }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

**But if I change `{{ $title->id }}` to `{{ $title->title }}` I get 404.**

And the controller is

```
public function getCurrent(Weekend $weekend)
{
    return view('pages.weekend')->with(['weekend'=> $weekend]);
}
```

Comment: if you want to use Implicit Route Model Binding you will have to look into how to adjust the Model or route definition to know what field it needs to be using for this purpose (by default it will use the 'id') ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name

Answer (score 0):

you can do just like that

```
Route::get('weekends/{weekend:title}',[PagesController::class,'getCurrent']);
```

Comment: So if I change the route to that and have my link to each individual page, like below, I still get a 404 ```@foreach($title as $title)
              <li><a href="weekends/{{$title->title}}">{{$title->title}}</a></li>
            @endforeach```

Comment: I think you need to run `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach changing the route binding key (which is set to the primary key by default). The easiest way is to add it to your implicit route binding (add `:title`):

```php
Route::get('weekends/{weekend:title}',[PagesController::class,'getCurrent']);
```

Another way to do it is by updating your model to change the default:

```php
public function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'title';
}
```

You can find more documentation on changing the key in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name).

Comment: Please add any long pieces of code and problems you are encountering to your question so they are easier to read.